# Move modifier to the top of the stack through python

Tags: python, modifiers

To my knowledge I believe modifiers can moved up one step in the list through executing this line `bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up()`

Is there anyway to move a modifier to the top of entire stack through python based on the modifier name or type ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by some simple scripting. I assume obj is filled with the object with the modifier stack

```
def modifiers_by_name(obj, name):
    """ Find all modifiers with a specific name in obj """
    return [x for x in obj.modifiers if x.name == name]

def modifiers_by_type(obj, typename):
    """ Find all modifiers with a specific type in obj """
    return [x for x in obj.modifiers if x.type == typename]

# move all "Screw" modifiers to the top
for modifier in reversed(modifiers_by_type(obj, "SCREW")):
    # while modifier not on top
    while obj.modifiers.find(modifier.name) != 0:
        # move it one more to the top.
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier=modifier.name)
```

Note I reversed the modifiers so the top "Screw" modifier will still be on the top after execution

Answer (score 5):

I use this script

```
import bpy
sel_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in sel_obj:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_to_index(modifier="Armature", index=0)
```

Link to the docs : [bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_to_index](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_to_index)